# Blender Guru Tutorial part 5: coffee cup bottom gets deformed

Tags: modeling

[image]

After selecting the orange part (alt+ctrl) and I try to scale it (s).
But then the very bottom of the cup becomes deformed..

Like this picture:
[image]

I am trying to figure out what I did wrong here. How do we scale it without deforming the bottom of the cup?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've done anything wrong. Could you upload the .blend file and have me look at it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I was able to scale down the cub without deformation after making the Proportional Editing Falloff small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're making the the cup after making the donut.
When you did the icing (frosting) on the donut, you will have set the Proportional Editing Falloff to Random to create that uneven edge of the icing running down the side of the donut.

As I recall, I made the same mistake, because Andrew (Blender Guru) omits to tell you to switch off proportional editing (probably because it's a series of videos that he made at different times).
So before scaling the cup, make sure that Proportional Editing  is switched to Disable.

Comment: That solved my problem! I minimized the size of the Proportional Editing Falloff circle and the bottom of the cup was not deformed afterwards. Thank you very much!